# Image is not coming in the crystal report using stored procedure

Tags: image, crystal-reports, report

I have a webapplication in asp.net 2.0 on that application i am using crystal report to display image from oracle database. on that report i am using dataset xsd with storedprocedure  to display data in crystal report. 
But the problem is when i am using stored procedure the image is not display in the report in case if i am using the simple sql the image is coming in the report.

Please give me solution

Thanks,
Pradyut

Comment: Is the image in the Oracle database or is it a path to the image? Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: the image is in the oracle database not the path of the image

Answer (score 0):

.GIF images are not really supported by Crystal Reports; I wasn't able to show those on the report, using stored procedure, only if they were in .JPG or .PNG format. 
 Change the format of the picture to .JPG, store it again in database and try.
HTH!